# C function works, C++ version does not

Tags: c++, c, linux, file-io

Have to use kernel to export a GPIO pin.  It's linux so its simple writing to a file.

C++ doesn't work:

```
std::ofstream file("/sys/class/gpio/export");
file << gpio;  // an int value
```

C does:

```
int fd, len;
char buf[MAX_BUF];

fd = open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY);
len = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", gpio);
write(fd, buf, len);
close(fd);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain "does not work"? What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: Well if it was successful a new directory gets created in /sys/class/gpio/.  When I compile the C function it works, the C++ just fails silently.

Comment: do you close your stream / flush it in your c++ version before checking for success?

Comment: I close it by letting it fall of the stack.

Comment: You can try adding error checks to diagnose the problem. `file.fail()`, `file.bad()`, `file.good()` are somethings to try.

Comment: It seems likely that the difference between these two cases might be in code you are not showing us. Can you reproduce the discrepancy with two complete, yet minimal, examples and post the entire code for these?

Comment: This question is answerable. VTRO.

Answer (score 3):

If the variable is a single byte, it will be output as a single `char` instead of a decimal number. Many characters aren't printable so you might not see the output - do a binary dump of the file to be sure.

To fix:

```
file << (int) gpio;
```

Comment: Very possible since I am storing gpio in a uint8_t (char).  Will test after I finish dinner with Bjarne Stroustrup. Sent from my iphone

Comment: being pedantic: `file << int(gpio);` is preferable.

Comment: Yes, you're missing the step where the `int` gets turned into a sequence of `char`.